# Change "," to "AND" when grouping placeholders in Node.js MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

As far as I understand, there are two primary ways of using placeholders in MySQL queries with Node.js:

```
UPDATE table SET column=? WHERE condition=?
```

... and

```
UPDATE table SET ? WHERE ?
```

I prefer the version #2 as it looks nicer and more flexible. Here's the code with one `WHERE` condition that works:

```
connection.query("UPDATE table SET ? WHERE ?", [
    {
        column1: value1,
        column2: value2,
        column3: value3
    },{
        condition4: value4
    }
], function(err, results) {
    console.log([err, results]);
});
```

Here's the code that doesn't because of the second WHERE condition added:

```
connection.query("UPDATE table SET ? WHERE ?", [
    {
        column1: value1,
        column2: value2,
        column3: value3
    },{
        condition4: value4,
        condition5: value5 // <----- note this
    }
], function(err, results) {
    console.log([err, results]);
});
```

It returns me:

> [Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' `condition5` = 'value5'' at line 1]
>   code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR'
>   errno: 1064
>   sqlState: '42000'
>   index: 0

I guess that's because it compiles the final query as `WHERE condition5='value5', condition5='value5'` which is incorrect SQL, the conditions should use `AND` or `OR` instead of that comma. Took me a while to figure out the Node doesn't automatically hadle that and joins the second array in the same way it joins the first array.

My fix was to rewrite that query to where it uses the individual placeholders this way hardcoding `AND` into the query manually.

So **here's my question** is there any way to tell Node to join the placeholders with `AND` when needed?

Also, how is the `SET ? WHERE ?` approach called? A search for 'grouped placehodlders' returns nothing.

Comment: mysql placeholders can represent VALUES only. you can't use them for keywords, identifiers (e.g. table/field names), etc...

Comment: It must be okay to use placeholders in `WHERE` as well right? I mean, `WHERE id='1'; DROP TABLES` is a classic isn't it?

Comment: Yes you can use placeholders anywhere but they only represent values. If you could put `AND` and the like in placeholders then you would be able to execute `DROP TABLES` too. Well, not exactly but the point is you can only use them to replace values -- strings or numbers.

Comment: just concat your strings if you need to. But for user-supplied data, use prepared statements or the equivalent for your db access layers. Else, yes, Bobby Tables comes a knockin

Comment: do you want to turn this into a how to question on imploded dynamic column names and values?